# How to refresh Kendo Grid on delete and add row action?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have data in the grid but after certain actions like (delete or add) i want to refresh grid , below i have method for delete that is deleting the row in Kendo grid. So i want to refresh grid once delete action is completed. How to achieve that task with below implementation...

So far tried code....

main.html

```
<div  kendo-grid="topRiskGrid" options="topRisksOptions" ></div>
```

main.ctrl

```
$scope.topRisksOptions = topRiskGridConfig.getTopRisksGrid();
            $scope.topRisksOptions.dataSource = rcsaAssessmentService.getTopRisksGridDataSource($stateParams.assessmentId);

var deleteCallBack = function () {
                $scope.topRiskGrid.dataSource.read();
            };
            $scope.deleteTopRisks = function(key){
              rcsaAssessmentFactory.deleteTopRisk(key.riskAssessmentKeyConcernKey,'RS_DELETED').then(function(){
                deleteCallBack();
              });
            }
```

main.factory

```
getTopRisksGridDataSource : function(assessmentId) {
                            return new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                type : 'json',
                                transport : {
                                    read : function(options) {

                                        return $http.get('app/assessment/rest/topRisks?riskAssessmentKey=' +assessmentId).success( 
                                                function(data) {
                                                    options.success(data.riskAssessmentKeyConcernDTOs);
                                                });
                                    }

                                },
                                pageSize : 5,

                            });
                        }
```

Comment: You delete the item on the client-side, but where do you delete it on the server? I'm assuming the relevant code is inside `rcsaAssessmentFactory.deleteTopRisk()`? Doing a read on the server without deleting the data there will just repopulate it like nothing happened.

Comment: thanks for response delete method  code is in factory delete is working good if you refresh page you can see that...But question is how i will refresh grid on that delete action ?

Comment: If what you're saying is correct, then performing a read on the grid's data source is how you'd refresh the data. It seems like this is exactly what you're asking the code to do, so, I'd do some deeper debugging on your part and stepping through your code. Be sure the timing of your delete and read are running properly and the data your receive back from your server is correct. We can't help you more without a demo that recreates the problem.

Comment: Additional question, is the data from your server get request cached perhaps?

Comment: Yes get method cached...i have error dataSource is undefined with above code...

Comment: What does `$scope.topRiskGrid` return within your `deleteCallback()` function?

Comment: it throws error ...dataSource is undefined..

Comment: That's not what I asked. Debug your code and step-into your `deleteCallback()` function when it's called and either hover over `$scope.topRiskGrid` or add it as a watch variable to see what it's value is.

Comment: ok i debug delete method and watch for grid value its showing undefined if you hover over on $scope.topRiskGrid

Comment: That's what I thought. Is `$scope` undefined as well?

Comment: No $scope has values

Comment: Then you should investigate further why your `$scope` does not have a value for `topRiskGrid`. I would bet the problem is somewhere else in your code that you haven't provided. [Here](http://jsbin.com/nicisaheca/1/edit?html,js,output) is a trivial jsBin example that references the grid within the controller. Maybe you can reproduce the problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btn_addContact").click(function(e) {
   // show the spinner
   kendo.ui.progress($("#contactdetailgrid"), true);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajaxdata/util_projectcontacts.php',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'text' }).done(function() {
      // reload the grid data
      $("#contactdetailgrid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
      $("#contactdetailgrid").data('kendoGrid').refresh();
      // hide the spinner
      kendo.ui.progress($("#contactdetailgrid"), false);
  });
});
```

I do it like this on my pages